# How to train a model for a dataset of images with 12 bands using TensorFlow's pix2pix notebook?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, generative-adversarial-network, cgan

I'm using TensorFlow's [pix2pix: Image-to-image translation with a conditional GAN notebook](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/pix2pix) to train a model for my dataset that consists of **multispectral satellite images with 12 bands like 512 x 512 x 12**.

As the original notebook is used for images with 256 x 256 x 3 dimensions, I had to apply some changes to a few of the important functions like `load()`, `Generator()`, `Discriminator()` and `generate_images()`.

My images have more than 3 bands (channels), specifically 12 bands. So, I have stored each 3 bands as an RBB (.png) image with a depth of 16 bit. That's why I have changed my load function in a way that it reads all four images that form a 12-band image and creates inputs with the shape: 512 x 512 x 12.

The Generator() function was also changed like below:

```
def Generator():
input_shape = (512, 512, 12)
inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=input_shape)

# Downsampling layers
down_stack = [
    downsample(64, 4, apply_batchnorm=False),  # First layer
    downsample(128, 4),  # Batchnorm applied
    downsample(256, 4),
    downsample(512, 4),
    downsample(512, 4),
    downsample(512, 4),
    downsample(512, 4),
    downsample(512, 4)
]

# Upsampling layers
up_stack = [
    upsample(512, 4, apply_dropout=True),  # Apply dropout in the first 3 layers
    upsample(512, 4, apply_dropout=True),
    upsample(512, 4, apply_dropout=True),
    upsample(512, 4),
    upsample(256, 4),
    upsample(128, 4),
    upsample(64, 4)
]

initializer = tf.random_normal_initializer(0., 0.02)
last = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(OUTPUT_CHANNELS, 4, strides=2,
                                       padding='same',
                                       kernel_initializer=initializer,
                                       activation='tanh')  # OUTPUT_CHANNELS should match your requirement

x = inputs

# Downsampling through the model
skips = []
for down in down_stack:
    x = down(x)
    skips.append(x)

skips = reversed(skips[:-1])

# Upsampling and establishing the skip connections
for up, skip in zip(up_stack, skips):
    x = up(x)
    if skip is not None:
        x = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate()([x, skip])

x = last(x)

return tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=x)
```

And I changed the Discriminator() like below:

```
def Discriminator():
initializer = tf.random_normal_initializer(0., 0.02)

# Input and target images will have 12 channels each
inp = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=[512, 512, 12], name='input_image')
tar = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=[512, 512, 12], name='target_image')

# Concatenate input and target images
x = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([inp, tar])  # (batch_size, 512, 512, 24)

down1 = downsample(64, 4, False)(x)  # (batch_size, 256, 256, 64)
down2 = downsample(128, 4)(down1)    # (batch_size, 128, 128, 128)
down3 = downsample(256, 4)(down2)    # (batch_size, 64, 64, 256)

zero_pad1 = tf.keras.layers.ZeroPadding2D()(down3)  # (batch_size, 66, 66, 256)
conv = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(512, 4, strides=1,
                              kernel_initializer=initializer,
                              use_bias=False)(zero_pad1)  # (batch_size, 63, 63, 512)

batchnorm1 = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(conv)

leaky_relu = tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU()(batchnorm1)

zero_pad2 = tf.keras.layers.ZeroPadding2D()(leaky_relu)  # (batch_size, 65, 65, 512)

last = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(1, 4, strides=1,
                              kernel_initializer=initializer)(zero_pad2)  # (batch_size, 62, 62, 1)

return tf.keras.Model(inputs=[inp, tar], outputs=last)
```

Finally, I changed the generate_images() function like below:

```
def generate_images(model, test_input, tar, save_dir='Some_Directory'):
prediction = model(test_input, training=True)

num_bands = 12
for i in range(0, num_bands, 3):
    bands = [i, i+1, i+2] if (i+2) < num_bands else [i, i+1, num_bands-1]
    plt.figure(figsize=(15, 5))

    display_list = [test_input[0], tar[0], prediction[0]]
    title = ['Input Image', 'Ground Truth', 'Predicted Image']

    for j in range(3):
        plt.subplot(1, 3, j+1)
        plt.title(title[j])

        # Normalize and select the bands for visualization
        image_display = tf.stack([display_list[j][..., band] for band in bands], axis=-1)
        image_display = (image_display + 1) / 2  # Rescale to [0, 1]

        plt.imshow(image_display)
        plt.axis('off')

    # Ensure the save directory exists
    os.makedirs(save_dir, exist_ok=True)
    plt.savefig(os.path.join(save_dir, f'generated_image_bands_{i}-{i+1}-{i+2}.png'))
    plt.close()

# Usage example
for example_input, example_target in test_dataset.take(1):
    generate_images(generator, example_input, example_target)
```

After these changes, when I run the fit() function to train the model using the code below:

```
fit(train_dataset, test_dataset, steps=40000)
```

Mostly after some steps (which can range from 1 to a few thousands), I get errors that are usually related to the shape of the tensors.

**These errors are like below:**

```
 tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: {{function_node __wrapped__StridedSlice_device_/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0}} slice index 1 of dimension 0 out of bounds. [Op:StridedSlice] name: strided_slice/ 
[[{{node EagerPyFunc}}]] [Op:IteratorGetNext] name: 


InvalidArgumentError: {{function_node __wrapped__StridedSlice_device_/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0}} Expected begin, end, and strides to be 1D equal size tensors, but got shapes [1], [1], and [3] instead. [Op:StridedSlice] name: strided_slice/


InvalidArgumentError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'conv2d_transpose_8' (type Conv2DTranspose).

{{function_node
 __wrapped__StridedSlice_device_/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0}}
Expected begin, end, and strides to be 1D equal size tensors, but got
shapes [1], [3], and [3] instead. [Op:StridedSlice] name:
model/conv2d_transpose_8/strided_slice/

Call arguments received by layer 'conv2d_transpose_8' (type
Conv2DTranspose):   • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(1, 256, 256, 128),
 dtype=float32)
```

Also, it is worth mentioning that sometimes when I run the `fit()` function, I get warnings like below but I don't think that these are causing the issue because I had similar errors in previous functions as well but they didn't affect the result.

```
WARNING:tensorflow:5 out of the last 5 calls to <function _BaseOptimizer._update_step_xla at 0x7927400fc1f0> triggered tf.function retracing. Tracing is expensive and the excessive number of tracings could be due to (1) creating @tf.function repeatedly in a loop, (2) passing tensors with different shapes, (3) passing Python objects instead of tensors. For (1), please define your @tf.function outside of the loop. For (2), @tf.function has reduce_retracing=True option that can avoid unnecessary retracing. For (3), please refer to https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/function#controlling_retracing and https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/function for  more details.
WARNING:tensorflow:6 out of the last 6 calls to <function _BaseOptimizer._update_step_xla at 0x7927400fc1f0> triggered tf.function retracing. Tracing is expensive and the excessive number of tracings could be due to (1) creating @tf.function repeatedly in a loop, (2) passing tensors with different shapes, (3) passing Python objects instead of tensors. For (1), please define your @tf.function outside of the loop. For (2), @tf.function has reduce_retracing=True option that can avoid unnecessary retracing. For (3), please refer to https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/function#controlling_retracing and https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/function for  more details.
```

I have tried changing the `BATCH_SIZE` from 1 to 2, reducing the number of samples significantly and changing some attributes inside the `Generator()` like changing the `apply_batchnorm` to True or False. How can I fix the issue and train my model for images with **512 x 512 x 12** dimensions?

**Edit: **Here is the result of running `generator.summary()`:

```
    Model: "model"
    __________________________________________________________________________________________________
    Layer (type)                Output Shape                 Param #   Connected to                  
    ==================================================================================================
    input_1 (InputLayer)        [(None, 512, 512, 12)]       0         []                            
                                                                                                    
    sequential_2 (Sequential)   (None, 256, 256, 64)         12288     ['input_1[0][0]']             
                                                                                                    
    sequential_3 (Sequential)   (None, 128, 128, 128)        131584    ['sequential_2[0][0]']        
                                                                                                    
    sequential_4 (Sequential)   (None, 64, 64, 256)          525312    ['sequential_3[0][0]']        
                                                                                                    
    sequential_5 (Sequential)   (None, 32, 32, 512)          2099200   ['sequential_4[0][0]']        
                                                                                                    
    sequential_6 (Sequential)   (None, 16, 16, 512)          4196352   ['sequential_5[0][0]']        
                                                                                                    
    sequential_7 (Sequential)   (None, 8, 8, 512)            4196352   ['sequential_6[0][0]']        
                                                                                                    
    sequential_8 (Sequential)   (None, 4, 4, 512)            4196352   ['sequential_7[0][0]']        
                                                                                                    
    sequential_9 (Sequential)   (None, 2, 2, 512)            4196352   ['sequential_8[0][0]']        
                                                                                                    
    sequential_10 (Sequential)  (None, 4, 4, 512)            4196352   ['sequential_9[0][0]']        
                                                                                                    
    concatenate (Concatenate)   (None, 4, 4, 1024)           0         ['sequential_10[0][0]',       
                                                                        'sequential_8[0][0]']        
                                                                                                    
    sequential_11 (Sequential)  (None, 8, 8, 512)            8390656   ['concatenate[0][0]']         
                                                                                                    
    concatenate_1 (Concatenate  (None, 8, 8, 1024)           0         ['sequential_11[0][0]',       
    )                                                                   'sequential_7[0][0]']        
                                                                                                    
    sequential_12 (Sequential)  (None, 16, 16, 512)          8390656   ['concatenate_1[0][0]']       
                                                                                                    
    concatenate_2 (Concatenate  (None, 16, 16, 1024)         0         ['sequential_12[0][0]',       
    )                                                                   'sequential_6[0][0]']        
                                                                                                    
    sequential_13 (Sequential)  (None, 32, 32, 512)          8390656   ['concatenate_2[0][0]']       
                                                                                                    
    concatenate_3 (Concatenate  (None, 32, 32, 1024)         0         ['sequential_13[0][0]',       
    )                                                                   'sequential_5[0][0]']        
                                                                                                    
    sequential_14 (Sequential)  (None, 64, 64, 256)          4195328   ['concatenate_3[0][0]']       
                                                                                                    
    concatenate_4 (Concatenate  (None, 64, 64, 512)          0         ['sequential_14[0][0]',       
    )                                                                   'sequential_4[0][0]']        
                                                                                                    
    sequential_15 (Sequential)  (None, 128, 128, 128)        1049088   ['concatenate_4[0][0]']       
                                                                                                    
    concatenate_5 (Concatenate  (None, 128, 128, 256)        0         ['sequential_15[0][0]',       
    )                                                                   'sequential_3[0][0]']        
                                                                                                    
    sequential_16 (Sequential)  (None, 256, 256, 64)         262400    ['concatenate_5[0][0]']       
                                                                                                    
    concatenate_6 (Concatenate  (None, 256, 256, 128)        0         ['sequential_16[0][0]',       
    )                                                                   'sequential_2[0][0]']        
                                                                                                    
    conv2d_transpose_8 (Conv2D  (None, 512, 512, 12)         24588     ['concatenate_6[0][0]']       
    Transpose)                                                                                       
                                                                                                    
    ==================================================================================================
    Total params: 54453516 (207.72 MB)
    Trainable params: 54442636 (207.68 MB)
    Non-trainable params: 10880 (42.50 KB)
    __________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: Would you please update 1st paragraph to clarify that you have satellite imagery which is not confined to just the visible spectrum?

Comment: @J_H Sure, I'm using multispectral satellite images with 12 bands. I did it, thanks for your attention.

Comment: I used your code to build a model, and what is really strange is that there is no `conv2d_transpose_8` layer. In your code are only 8 `Conv2D_Transpose` layers, and naming begins from 0, so the last transpose layer is `conv2d_transpose_7`. Are you sure you don't have anything else added to the code?

Comment: @mhenning I edited my question and added the result of running `generator.summary()` to the end of it.  It seems like I get the layers correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is just a guess, because it is too long for a comment, but maybe it helps.
I tested your code with the data from the [pix2pix link](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/pix2pix) and transformed it to `(512, 512, 12)` to fit your model architecture. I could not replicate your error, but ran into the error

> ValueError: Input 0 of layer "model_1" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 512, 512, 12), found shape=(512, 512, 12)

which makes sense, because with `take(1)` (or `take` in general) you don't get batches, but iterate over a list of single samples. (`take(4000)` generates a list of 4000 single samples, which all have shape `(512, 512, 12)`, missing the batch dimension.)
My solution to this is expanding the single sample with a batch dimension:

```py
if len(input_image.shape) != 4:
    input_image = tf.expand_dims(input_image, 0)
```

(Alternatively, you can batch the `Dataset` with

```py
train_dataset = train_dataset.batch(1).prefetch(1)  # prefetch is optional here, but makes training faster
```

and then change your training loop from

```py
for step, (input_image, target) in train_ds.repeat().take(steps).enumerate():
```

to

```py
for step, (input_image, target) in train_ds.enumerate():  # input_image.shape=(1, 512, 512, 12)
```

I think you'll loose your steps counter, but it would be more efficient with `prefetch`, `cache` and so on. See [here for performance tips](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data_performance).)

As for your warning

> WARNING:tensorflow:5 out of the last 5 calls to <function _BaseOptimizer._update_step_xla at 0x7927400fc1f0> triggered tf.function retracing. Tracing is expensive and the excessive number of tracings could be due to **(1) creating @tf.function repeatedly in a loop, (2) passing tensors with different shapes, (3) passing Python objects instead of tensors.** For (1), please define your @tf.function outside of the loop. For (2), @tf.function has reduce_retracing=True option that can avoid unnecessary retracing. For (3), please refer to https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/function#controlling_retracing and https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/function for  more details.

(1) is most likely out, because I did not get it.
That leaves (2) and (3). You should check you input data if all samples have the same shape (2) and if some are objects (3)(pretty unlikely, but hey).
[This link](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/34025#issuecomment-557668541) mentions variable length input and single sample input, where the fix is to expand the first dimension, just as I had to to run the code.

You could also test your network with dummy data

```py
x = tf.random.uniform((100, 512, 512, 12))
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x, x))
```

If this does not throw an error, you can be sure that it has to be your input data.

Comment: But as I've already concatenated the four images the form a multispectral image to a single one in my modified load function, isn't it OK to use take()? Could you explain more?

Comment: Rougly speaking, `take(10)` gives you a list of 10 individual images, each `(512, 512, 12)`. But the model always expects a batch of images `(x, 512, 512, 12)`, where x stands for the batch, for instance `2` for 2 images. If you have a single image, you have to add the batch dimension `(1, 512, 512, 12)` for TF to work with it. Do you not get this error? What TF version do you have?

Comment: I'm using a code like this in my train_step() function: `input_image = tf.expand_dims(input_image, 0)` and `target = tf.expand_dims(target, 0)`.
And the version that I'm using is 2.15.0

Comment: This looks right for single images, it adds the batch dimension. Please test your training loop with dummy data, or test if your images have different shapes. In my personal experience, most of the time the retracing warning is there because the input shapes change. It's strange that I did not encounter any of the errors you mentioned while my loop is exactly like the one from your question.

Comment: Why are you using this condition `if len(input_image.shape) != 4:`?
Why are we using 4?
When I test my model using a code like below, I don't have any errors: `for example_input, example_target in test_dataset.take(1): generate_images(generator, example_input, example_target)`. What if I add epoch logic instead of steps? Like `fit(train_dataset, test_dataset, steps_per_epoch=1000, epochs=40)`.

Comment: I test against a 4-tuple, because thats what the model expeccts. For images (or more specific, convolution layer as first layer), the input should be the shape `(batch, height, width, channels)`, which are 4 values. If the input does ot have 4, it has most likely only 3 dims, and then `tf.expand_dim` is called. If there are already 4 dims, it is skipped.

Comment: For the epoch logic, you can do that, but then you have to change the training loop logic you hae right now. I never worked wiht `steps_per_epoch` before, I think it would be cleaner if you'd do `epochs = 40000//len(train_dataset)`. This way, the whole dataset is used per eoch. Also, this is getting a bit off-topic here. Did you test with dummy data?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256364/discussion-between-naser-sadeghi-and-mhenning).

Comment: I added more details about the dataset in the chat. I'd really appreciate it if you check them.